# What is wrong with sqlite3_step()?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a C++ program which has this function that at some point calls sqlite3_step(). It turn out that when sqlite3_step() function is reached the program clashes with a message "The program has unexpectedly finished." What exactly Am I doing wrong here?

```
bool Database::removeRepository(string repoName)
{
    string sql = "DELETE FROM ";
    sql += tableName + " WHERE NAME='" + repoName + "'";

    sqlite3_stmt* deleteStmt = nullptr;

    int prep_results = sqlite3_prepare_v2(connection, sql.c_str(), sql.size(), &deleteStmt, NULL);

    int results = sqlite3_step(deleteStmt);

    sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);

    if(results == SQLITE_DONE)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Where is `connection` coming from?

Comment: You've forgotten to check the function return values. They should tell you whether, and why, they failed.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, connection is a private class variable that is initiated by the constructor. Other functions that uses connection work ok.

Comment: @avakar: I understand that string manipulation is not a good idea, but in this situation I can not imagine where SQL injection could come from, I mean Am still testing the code myself.

Comment: There is something wrong with `connection`. The code you've shown does not cause the problem.

Comment: @CL: there are other functions in the same class that use connection without problem. What could be the probable issue that is specific to this function? connection is also initiated by calling sqlite3_open_v2() from the constructor!

Comment: Some other code closes or overwrites `connection`.

Comment: Just out if curiosity, why are you preparing the statement in the first place? Won't a simple `sqlite3_exec` suffice for this type of statement? - You don't seem to be binding any parameters, nor stepping through(pulling) any query result, so I can't see why not.

Comment: @HVS, initially I had the same thought but changed my mind after reading a book on SQLite which discourages use of sqlite3_exec.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly your `sqlite3_prepare_v2` call is failing. You should check the value of `prep_results` and see what the value is (there is a list [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html))

Comment: sqlite3_prepare_v2 returns 0 which is SQLITE_OK!